# Using Angular Factory in basic util.js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I was wondering if anyone could help me out.  I’ve created a factory which is used to store and update a list of variables/functions.

```
(function() {
angular.module('myApp.Module').factory(
        'MyFactory',
        function() {                

              return {
                    getExampleData: function() {
                        return "Hello, World!";
                    }
              };
        });
}());
```

I have created an example above. I can successfully call myFactory.getExampleData  (and get “Hello, World!” returned) from any controller etc that has the factory injected as you would expect.  However I have also  a basic util.js class which is basically a list of utility functions to apply logic to some data.  Ie.

```
function addNumbers(number1, number2){

    return number1 + number2;
 }
```

As you can see I'm aware I can pass parameters in and do some logic on them and return the result,  However, in one of my functions within the util.js file I need to access the factory to call a function which changes a variable in the Factory.  Is this possible as since its simply a basic util class and has no injection etc how can I use "myFactory".

```
function addNumbers(number1, number2){
    //Want to be able to make a call to myFactory.getExampleData from here
    return number1 + number2;
 }
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can't you pass `myFactory` or `myFactory.getExampleData(whatYouWant)` as an argument to your function? If i understood well, your Factory will be available where you will call this function?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had originally tried that (first thing I tried and couldn't figure out why it wasnt working for me) I must have had a typo or something I couldnt see because after retrying it is working.  Thanks for the help :)

Comment: The functions within your Util class shouldn't depend on your factory. That would result in bad coupling. If it really requires access to the factory, I would refactor the util.js file into an angular service/factory, which can then inject the dependent factory.

Comment: actually NikolajDamLarsen's comment is better. Mine is rather a quick fix than a clean solution

Comment: I agree with Nikolaj but also wonder about what the user really needs. The example code is purposely oversimplified. Are we talking about application architecture or is the user just asking how to manually perform angularjs based injection and the example is just an example? To be clearer: if you are asking for a suggestion about how to design your app, you should probably consider following Nikolaj advice. If you just need to know how to do manual injection, please clarify that and I think I probably know what you need